# Template match and attribute to node

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

A customer supplies a consolidated XML which needs to be converted the desired format, this is done with the following XSLT.

The only issue is the invoice entity "number", how can I get the correct invoice number as a node  in the XML?

XML:

```
<invoices>
  <invoice number="5555">
    <order_id>
        <ordernumber>1000</ordernumber>
    </order_id>
    <general_info>General A</general_info>
    <address>Adress A</address>
    <products>
        <product>
            <id>A</id>
            <item/>
            <item/>
        </product>
        <product>
            <id>B</id>
            <item/>
            <item/>
        </product>
        <product>
            <id>C</id>
            <item/>
            <item/>
        </product>
    </products>
</invoice>
<invoice number="7777">
    <order_id>
        <ordernumber>2000</ordernumber>
    </order_id>
    <general_info>General B</general_info>
    <address>Adress B</address>
    <products>
        <product>
            <id>D</id>
            <item/>
            <item/>
        </product>
    </products>
</invoice>
```

XSLT:

```
    <xsl:template match="invoices">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="invoice/products/product"/>
     </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="product">
     <invoice>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="../../general_info"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="../../address"/>
        <invoicenumber><xsl:value-of select="../../../invoice/@number"/></invoicenumber>
    </invoice>
</xsl:template>
```

With the current XSLT the invoicenumber is always 5555.
How can i get the correct invoicenumber with each product? (item D should have 7777)

Current output:

```
<invoices>
 <invoice>
  <product>
     <id>A</id>
     <item/>
     <item/>
  </product>
  <general_info>General A</general_info>
  <address>Adress A</address>
  <invoicenumber>5555</invoicenumber>
</invoice>
<invoice>
  <product>
     <id>B</id>
     <item/>
     <item/>
  </product>
  <general_info>General A</general_info>
  <address>Adress A</address>
  <invoicenumber>5555</invoicenumber>
</invoice>
<invoice>
  <product>
     <id>C</id>
     <item/>
     <item/>
  </product>
  <general_info>General A</general_info>
  <address>Adress A</address>
  <invoicenumber>5555</invoicenumber>
</invoice>
<invoice>
  <product>
     <id>D</id>
     <item/>
     <item/>
  </product>
  <general_info>General B</general_info>
  <address>Adress B</address>
  <invoicenumber>5555</invoicenumber>
 </invoice>
</invoices>
```

Desired output:

```
<invoices>
 <invoice>
  <product>
     <id>A</id>
     <item/>
     <item/>
  </product>
  <general_info>General A</general_info>
  <address>Adress A</address>
  <invoicenumber>5555</invoicenumber>
</invoice>
<invoice>
  <product>
     <id>B</id>
     <item/>
     <item/>
  </product>
  <general_info>General A</general_info>
  <address>Adress A</address>
  <invoicenumber>5555</invoicenumber>
</invoice>
<invoice>
  <product>
     <id>C</id>
     <item/>
     <item/>
  </product>
  <general_info>General A</general_info>
  <address>Adress A</address>
  <invoicenumber>5555</invoicenumber>
</invoice>
<invoice>
  <product>
     <id>D</id>
     <item/>
     <item/>
  </product>
  <general_info>General B</general_info>
  <address>Adress B</address>
  <invoicenumber>7777</invoicenumber>
 </invoice>
</invoices>
```

Comment: You've labelled your question xslt 2.0, but if you were actually using XSLT 2.0, I would expect the instruction `<xsl:value-of select="../../../invoice/@number"/>` to print ALL invoice numbers, whitespace separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate up to the ancestor `invoice` with e.g. `<invoicenumber><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::invoice/@number"/></invoicenumber>`.